How to filter a query in Django for week_day using a specific timezone?
I am trying to filter data by the day of the week.  That's easy enough with the week_day filter.  The problem is, since all dates are stored as UTC, that is how it's filtered.  How can I localize a query?
For instance, trying to count all the records that have been created on specific days, I use this:
chart_data = [
            data.filter(created__week_day=1).count(),  # Sunday
            data.filter(created__week_day=2).count(),  # Monday
            data.filter(created__week_day=3).count(),  # Tuesday
            data.filter(created__week_day=4).count(),  # Wednesday
            data.filter(created__week_day=5).count(),  # Thursday
            data.filter(created__week_day=6).count(),  # Friday
            data.filter(created__week_day=7).count(),  # Saturday
        ]

How can I get these queries to count those records localized to the 'America/New_York' timezone, for instance?

I came up with a solution, albeit it is different than I assumed it would be, and it is probably not the most efficient way to do it.
from .models import Track
from collections import Counter
import pytz


data = Trackers.objects.all()
days_of_week = []
for tracked in data:
    # Convert created time to US/Eastern timezone
    created_eastern = tracked.created.astimezone(tz)
    # Get the day of the week (0=Monday, 6=Sunday)
    day_of_week = created_eastern.weekday()
    # Append the day of the week to the list
    days_of_week.append(day_of_week)
# Count occurrences of each day
day_counts = Counter(days_of_week)
# Initialize a list for 7 days with zeros
chart_data = [0 for _ in range(7)]
for day_number, count in sorted(day_counts.items()):
    chart_data[day_number] = count

This gives what I need, but it seems it should be able to be done completely in the query, which may be a more elegant solution.
